# Functional equation $f(f(x)y+x)=f(x)f(y)+f(x)$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations, integers

Find all functions $ f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$:

**i)** if $x \ne y$ then $f(x) \ne f(y)$;

**ii)** $f(f(x)y+x)=f(x)f(y)+f(x)$.

**My work**. 
It is easy to see that a function $f(x)=kx$, where $k=const$ ( $k \in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{0\}$ ), is a solution of the problem. But is this the only solution? It is easy to see that $f(0)=0$.

Comment: To state the obvious: $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ for this to give a function mapping integers to integers.

Comment: and $k \ne 0$, because the condition **i)** must be true

Comment: About the only possibly-useful observation I can make is that $1+f(y)=\dfrac{f(f(x)y+x)}{f(x)}.$ Hence the RHS is actually independent of $x$, so $f(y) = \dfrac{f(f(1)y+1)}{f(1)}-1$ for all $y$.

Comment: Try playing with small cases (e.g. set $f(1)=5$) and seeing what happens. Busy right now, but I'll post a full answer later if it's still unanswered.

Comment: See pco's solution of problem 354 in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h350187.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I voted +1 :) I love functional equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A paraphrase of the [solution by pco at AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h350187p3260946)*:

1. By setting $x=y=0$ we get that $f(0)=0$. Since $f$ is injective, we have $f(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\neq 0$. In particular, $a:=f(1)\neq 0$.
2. By setting $x=1$, we get for all $y$: $$f(ay+1)=a(f(y)+1)$$
3. In particular, $$f(a+1)=a(a+1)$$
4. By setting $x=a\tilde x+1$ and $y=1$ we get for all $\tilde x\in\mathbb Z$: $$f\big(f(a\tilde x+1)+a\tilde x+1\big)\overset{2.}=f\big(a(f(\tilde x)+1)+a\tilde x+1\big)=a(f(\tilde x)+1)(a+1).$$
5. By setting $x=a+1$ and $y=\tilde x$ we get for all $\tilde x$:
   $$f\big(f(a+1)\tilde x+a+1\big)\overset{3.}=f\big(a(a+1)\tilde x+a+1\big)=f(a+1) f(\tilde x)+f(a+1)\overset{3.}=a(f(\tilde x)+1)(a+1).$$

It follows that for all $\tilde x\in\mathbb Z$, $$f\big(a(a+1)\tilde x+a+1\big)=f\big(a(f(\tilde x)+1)+a\tilde x+1\big)$$

and thus since $f$ is injective $$a(a+1)\tilde x+a+1=a(f(\tilde x)+1)+a\tilde x+1$$

or $$a^2\tilde x+a=a f(\tilde x)+a$$

which implies that the only solutions are of the form $$f(\tilde x)=a\tilde x.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!